# What type cable and size should I use for my shop?

Tags: electrical, wiring

My existing overhead wire is triplex 1/0,  2 insulated  and one bare. The power company is out of the picture because they do not provide service to a customer supplied pole.

My existing wire is at a 20 ' pole , 5 feet from the weatherhead at the shop. The mast is 10' ,  2 inch galv. pipe with a lbr going into the shop behind the load center.

Questions are:  Can I just splice in an 18' section of 1/0 triplex and be done with it?

Should I splice in a 4/0 triplex using a mechanical reducer splice? 4/0 is because of the weatherhead and mast. Not sure if required because it is not a residence.

Should I even use a triplex wire with a bare neutral in a metal conduit?

Items on the service are :

- deep well pump 20a
- Welder 50a
- Compressor 30a
- Lift 30a
- Lights 15a
- Outlet 20a
- Outlet 20a

[image][image]

Comment: Could you also include a picture of the shop breaker box showing the breakers and also the grounding system... either via ground rods or UFER

Comment: No breakers are installed yet. I have a 7/16 copper rod 3 feet behind the pole with 4ga copper running to the load center.

Comment: The load center should have a main disconnect

Comment: It has one 400 ft away by the meter pole. Should I have another or is the 200 amp main at the load center  good enough?

Comment: You probably do wise by checking the supply voltage is high enough to compensate for the voltage drop.  Some machines won't work very well if they do not get the minimal listed voltage requirements.

Comment: This was A pole barn for the last 40 years with lots of machinery and welders running. I just had to tear it down because of termites. Now I have a new metal building trying to install new electric.

Comment: Just to give you an example of the voltage drop from only **60A** using 2/0 aerial AL single conductors 60×.159×400×2÷1000 = 7.6% VD  That's almost 17 volts and if the supply is 230 the shop gets around 212.  This is probably okay but if you increase the load you can expect to drop more voltage.

Comment: A neutral is never bare! This is your equipment grounding conductor. To meet current code if you want 240v you will need to upgrade your feeder cable.

Comment: Ed, I have 220 at the pole now. It only had the triplex cable when I bought the property.    Should I replace 400+ feet of cable or use what I have like my plan? The bare wire is the neutral and I have added a ground at the new shop.

Comment: I will check the voltage  at the pole in the morning. I will  also check it at the meter.

Comment: What's the I1eff for the welder, or the max duty cycle for that matter?  Also, where's the power meter? At the pole next to the barn, at a different pole on the property, or at the house?

Comment: Ed, this is what the power company installed 30 years ago. I don't know what the code is in my county, but I think they didn't care much 30 years ago. They pretty much don't care today. NEC is the best I can figure out that they go by,  but definitely not enforced.

Comment: Threephase, the meter is 400 ft away on another pole on the property. It is just the way they did it 40 years ago. The original install was a buried cable 400 ft  50 years ago. It was cut several times and the power company installed three poles and the triplex cable only 2 insulated and that was 40 years ago. Burying a new cable is not my option due to a road and the plumbing for the deep well.  If I don't have much of s voltage drop, can I safely use the existing 1/0  triplex cable and could I splice on a new section of 18' and run it through the mast to the power center.

Comment: Ed, with my set up now, will I even be able to get gfi circuit to work? The bare wire is connected to the ground wire on the poles and to the neutral from the transformer. There never was a ground rod installed until now. My home looks like it has the same setup, with the exception it does go underground with a bigger cable.

Comment: Kris, the voltage at the shop reads 240 with no loads. No difference with a 5 amp saw running. However, I did notice a potential problem . I told you that my overhead line is 1/0 triplex. I just this morning discovered that my main was tapped off the transformer with a much smaller diameter cable going to the meter. So the power company can take care of that issue.  I am guessing 2ga or 4ga. It has been working for several years but I don't know how it has not burned through and shorted the transformer. I have a former power company electrician coming out to look at my situation.

Comment: The Code has changed in the last 30 years.  Separate neutral and ground is now required on feeder.   3-wire bare neutral is OK for a **service** but is not appropriate for a **feeder**.  It really, really pays to research exhaustively before dropping cash on table. Many, *most especially big-box stores*, will cheerfully sell you the wrong thing without asking what you are doing.  Big-box will even straight-faced recommend the wrong thing. This is why I buy from electrical supply (that, and price). **Now here's a question for you. Can you find/uncover the old cable??**

Comment: There was no old cable or so called service entrance. The triplex 1/0 was connected directly the the old panel. Half exposed to the elements. I tore the old pole barn down and put up a new building. So I was looking for a service entrance cable to connect to my existing overhead cable. I haven't bought anything yet. It looks like 4/0 is the only thing the supply houses have near me.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

We simply need more information:  How far to the shop?  Is the meter base at the shop?  A picture/diagram of property would be helpful; include distances.

If the panel shown here is equipped with a main breaker, there is no need for an additional disconnect.  I see no need for the pole as all.  Just strike to the mast.

If it is indeed 400-feet to the meter base you are going to have a fairly serious voltage drop problem.  The voltage is based upon the amount of actual current used at any one time.

If the pole is required for ground clearance than don't splice at the pole just strike to the pole and continue to the weather head.

Technically you need a quad-plex or 4-wires as the feeder.  After the service the neutral is separated from the ground. I would recommend an underground feeder.  I would put it down 4-5 feet for protection.

If you could give me the estimated max current draw at any one time we could recommend a wire size. That means that when you strike an arc with the welder what is the actual current draw of the welder on the circuit.  And when the pump actually runs and is pumping full bore, what is the current draw on the pump motor. And when the compressor is running nearing the shut-off point what is that motor drawing.  And what is the actual amp draw on the lights? Then throw in 10 or 12 amps for power and bench tools per number of men that will be using the building at any one time. With this we can give you wire size.

Do you ever plan to heat the building?

Comment: Thank you Paul! The meter is 400 feet away  with a disconnect. The shop will only be used when needed snd not on a daily basis. The welded is the largest draw max 50 amp snd I hardly think I will need to set it that high. The air compressor is the next largest user at 30 amp max. It may kick on when welding is going on and I never noticed any change in sound while welding. I have thought of a heater but not at this time. I do understand that could be an issue later down the road when I'm gone. I'd hate to stick the problem with my sons. I need the clearance so that is why I put in the pole.

Comment: Paul,  the welder can peak at 50a. The compressor is rated at 25a. When I replaced the pump 5 years ago each leg showed 8 amps at turn on and tapered off to 6.5a. Lighting is all led, 16 at 47 watt each. I exterior light at 150 watts. I do not have the lift yet but it calls for a 30 amp circuit. I wish I could go underground. The plumbing for the deep well is in the way and was the reason the first underground cable was cut.  3 others tap into my pump house for water, right where  the cable was buried.

Comment: Thanks to all for the help. I am having an electrician come out to evaluate my situation. I will come back and tell you what the resolution was.  I am thinking a new quad-plex as was mention here.

Comment: Good Plan. Good Luck.

Comment: I am not much interest to an electrician I guess. Can't get anyone out to the house. Still not done yet.

Comment: I had a lineman come out to look at my situation.  I have 2ga triplex off the transformer to the meter base. I have a ground connected there and to the main load center. From the main load center I have a 4/0 triplex cable running  400' to my shop. I was told to

Comment: hook up the ground rod that I installed at the shop,  to the neutral bar because I don't  have a ground coming in from main. He is going to have the power company replace the 2ga wire off the transformer. Does this sound okay for my situation, since replacing the entire 440 feet is not goin

Comment: giing to happen soon.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that since you are not replacing the overhead line, (and since doing so would be onerous), this setup is **grandfathered**.  As such, you will need to bond neutral and ground in your barn panel.

If you're feeding straight off the meter, then it's a bit of a weird setup, with the potential for problems.  If you're feeding off a breaker in your main panel, just know that the grandfathering introduces some safety hazards, and you would never do it on a new installation.

Now, you will have some pretty brutal voltage drop.  If that becomes a problem and you want to do all of the following: reduce your voltage drop by 75%, b) double your current capacity (at this doubled capacity voltage drop will be half what it is now), and c) **make this setup a whole lot safer**... then let us know and we can advise a very good way to do that.   It will not require replacing the overhead line, just installing some equipment at both ends.

Comment: I may want to make my setup safer. Before I buy 20 feet of 4/0-4/0-4/0  SEU  cable what else do I need? I do have my 4/0 to 1/0 reducer crimps.